# Delegate Object Error

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates

I am relatively new to C#, and trying to learn how to call a `delegate` from a `Dictionary`. I am using a `<string, Delegate` pairing. My test class is as follows:

```
namespace DelegatesHowTo
{
    class Program
    {
        protected delegate bool ModuleQuery(string parameter);

        static Dictionary<string, ModuleQuery> queryDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ModuleQuery>();

        public Program()
        {
            queryDictionary.Add("trustQuery", new ModuleQuery(queryTrustedStore));
            queryDictionary.Add("tokenQuery", new ModuleQuery(queryTokenStore));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ModuleQuery MyQuery = new ModuleQuery(queryTrustedStore);
            queryDictionary.TryGetValue("trustQuery", out MyQuery);

            bool testQuery = MyQuery("TestTrusted");
            Console.WriteLine("Trusted: {0}", testQuery);
        }

        static bool queryTrustedStore(string parameter)
        {
            return parameter.Equals("TestTrusted");
        }

        static bool queryTokenStore(string parameter)
        {
            return parameter.Equals("TestToken");
        }
    }
}
```

However, the line `bool testQuery = MyQuery("TestTrusted");` throws `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DelegatesHowTo.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\...`

I was under the impression that I was instantiating an object with `ModuleQuery MyQuery = new ModuleQuery(queryTrustedStore);`. I guess this isn't true, though? Could someone point me in the right direction, as to how this can be corrected?

Comment: Your test program is borken, the Program class constructor doesn't run since you never create an instance of it.  Move the Dictionary<>.Add() statements inside Main() or use a static constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never ran the `Program()` constructor.

Therefore, the dictionary remains empty, and `TryGetValue()` sets the `out` parameter to `null`.

Comment: What SLaks is trying to say in his typically abbreviated way is that the usual entry point for your program is the `Main()` function, not the class constructor method.  Perform your `Add` method calls in the `Main()` function.

Comment: And OP seems to add values to static dictionary from instance constructor. This will fail if second instance is created. changing it to static constructor will be better